# Webpack and three.js in forge applications

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm struggling a bit with the new viewer version 7 and the inclusion of three.js. According to

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/webpack-and-threejs-forge-applications

it is necessary to define three.js as external. But where exactly do I do that? The viewer is embedded in an Angular environment.

Comment: I also always get the error: Can't use multiple render targets. Falling back to two passes. 36054

Comment: If you are not using THREE in your own app there’s no need to reference that THREE externally again - that blog was to address the need to reference THREE for use in your own components. And these had nothing to do with THREE references either are you using the latest v7.2 and have you tried to clear the browser’s cache? if the issue persists pls upload the problematic model to weTransfer/dropbox/Gdrvie and send the link over to forge.help@autodesk.com so we can take a look.

Comment: The thing is, that I'm using THREE in some of my components. Clearing the cache didn't help. But if I'm on the Edge Browser, the error is the following: WEBGL11163: clear: Invalid framebuffer operation.

Comment: Will you get the same errors if you leave everything out but just Viewer and the model? If the errors persist then send us the model so we can look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add THREE as dependency in package.json and use the THREE global loaded by the viewer. If you just need the THREE types: (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/forge-viewer)