# trying to load multiple documents

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

trying to implement clash detection but a java script error occurs can you please help me to solve the problem

**Can't use multiple render targets. Falling back to two passes. 36061**

Comment: Could it be that you are referencing THREE.JS? (and that's causing problems?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817235/webpack-and-three-js-in-forge-applications
Which Viewer version are you using? 
Does the error only happen when you load a second model?

Comment: viewer version 7.19.1

Comment: Could you please answer the other questions as well? Also, when you debug into your code, when exactly does this error appear in the console - after the execution of which exact line? Does anything appear in the Viewer? Maybe you could provide screenshots?